# How do I add a javascript variable to shadow DOM?

Tags: jquery, shadow-dom

I have a shadow dom element I create like this...

```
this.wrapper = document.createElement("div");
this.shadow = this.wrapper.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
this.$el.appendChild(this.wrapper);
```

Now I have looking at assigning a JS variable in the shadow dom similar to on the window. If I was using window I would do something like.

```
window.foo = "bar";
```

How can I do this same thing only encapsulate the scope to just the shadow dom?

Example:

Old Way:

```js
var wrapper = document.createElement( 'div' )
window.foo = function(){
  console.log("Do Something");
}
wrapper.innerHTML = '<div onclick="foo()"></div>'
document.body.appendChild( this.wrapper )
```

Shadow Dom

```js
var wrapper = document.createElement( 'div' )
var shadow = this.wrapper.attachShadow( {mode: 'open'} )
shadow.innerHTML = '<div onclick="this.shadow.foo()"></div>'
document.body.appendChild( this.wrapper )
shadow.foo = function(){
  console.log("Do Something");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To gain access to the `shadowRoot` entity from inside the Shadow DOM, you should invoke the [`getRootNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/getRootNode) method.

```
<div onclick="this.getRootNode().foo()">Click</div>
```

Then you can call the function attached as a `shadowroot` property.

See the complete example:

```js
var wrapper = document.createElement( 'div' )
var shadow = wrapper.attachShadow( {mode: 'open'} )
shadow.innerHTML = '<div onclick="this.getRootNode().foo()">Click</div>'
document.body.appendChild( wrapper )
shadow.foo = function() {
  console.log("Do Something")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not a current (good?) practice, you could assign a property to the shadow root :

```
this.shadow.foo = "bar"
```

Example:

```js
var wrapper = document.createElement( 'div' )
var shadow = this.wrapper.attachShadow( {mode: 'open'} )
shadow.innerHTML = 'hello world'
document.body.appendChild( this.wrapper )
shadow.foo = 'bar'
console.log( wrapper.shadowRoot.foo )
```

Comment: Is that accessible from the dom the same way a global variable would be? For example could I add a function to Shadow and have it used for onclick etc?

Comment: Yes in the open mode, no in thé closed mode

Comment: Darn didn't work for me with this.shadow.event = function(){} and <div onclick="event()">

Comment: " doSomething is not defined"

Comment: Updated the snippet to try and give you a better idea of what I am looking for. I think I might be able to do it if after setting the HTML I do a dom search for the element and manually attach it but I haven't gotten there yet

Comment: Sorry I think I edited you example instead of injecting it into mine. I hope I got it right changing it back but double check for me.

Comment: @Jackie I rolled backed and post another anwser to your 2nd question.